# Chaining promises synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda, promise

I'm working with AWS Lambda. I'm trying to decrypt the key in a async function & then making a POST request to another URL which depends on getting the key first from the first call.

```
module.exports = function (payload) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var headers = config.Headers;
        decrypt(headers.Authorization)
            .then(function (auth_token) {
                headers.Authorization = 'Basic ' + auth_token;
                console.log('dispatch got the key from kms');
                return makePostCall(headers, payload);
            })
             .then(function (changeNumber){
                 console.log(changeNumber);
                 return resolve(changeNumber);
            })
            .catch (function (error) {
                console.error('Error during dispatch: ' + error);
                return reject(error);
            });
    });
};
```

The `decrypt` & `makePostCall` call both return either `reject` or `resolve`. Runs fine locally, but when running on Lambda, runs successfully only some times, which led me to believe that issue is with asynchronous calling of the `makePostCall` function. The error I get(from `catch`) is:

```
Error during dispatch: null
```

I need to run decrypt first-> Get the key -> then MakePostCall.

**Edit:** makePostCall looks like this:

```
function makePostCall(headers, payload) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const url = config.serviceNowEndpoint + config.serviceNowChangeUri;
        request.post({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: headers,
            json: payload
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error) {
                return resolve(body.change_request.number);
            }
            else {
                return reject(new Error('Returned with status code: ' + response.statusCode));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**More Edit**: As per *@Jaromanda X*'s suggestion, modified the code to:

```
module.exports = function (payload) {
    var headers = config.Headers;
    return decrypt(headers.Authorization)
        .then(function (auth_token) {
            headers.Authorization = 'Basic ' + auth_token;
            console.log('dispatch got the key from kms');
            return makePostCall(headers, payload);
        })
        .catch (function (error) {
            console.error('Error during dispatch: ' + error);
            return error;
        });
};
```

Problem still persists though. Runs fine locally, but async on Lambda

**Edit** adding decrypt code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const config = require('../config/config');

module.exports = function(token)  {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const kms = new AWS.KMS({ region: config.aws_region.region});

        const params = {
            CiphertextBlob: new Buffer(token, 'base64')
        };
        kms.decrypt(params, function (err, data) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log('decrypted successfully');
                return resolve(data.Plaintext.toString());
            } else {
                return reject(`${err.message}`);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: What is `makePostCall`? It shouldn’t really reject with `null`.

Comment: If `decrypt` and `makePostCall` are already returning promises, there is no need to wrap them in a new promise

Comment: @Ryan added the code for makePostCall.

Comment: FYI - [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4nsmza6g/) is what your first code block SHOULD look like (it is functionally equivalent) ... oh, and `I need to run decrypt first-> Get the key -> then MakePostCall.` yes, that what the code does

Comment: @PatrickEvans This module also returns promise to another module. I'm fairly new to promises. Is there another way to run then synchronously?

Comment: does the function reach this line: `console.log('dispatch got the key from kms');` and the other `console.log(changeNumber);` ?

Comment: @Gogo - you can **not** make asynchronous code synchronous - just think about it for a second and you should realise why that is impossible

Comment: You can use **async/await** if you want a more sync style

Comment: @Hosar yeah it reaches those lines but only _sometimes_

Comment: @JaromandaX but surely should be able to wait for key to decrypt before making the next call? Sorry if I'm not making much sense. Thanks for the fiddle btw :)

Comment: `surely should be able to wait for key to decrypt` - yes, that what I would think decrypt does, returns a promise (not a "resolve or reject" as you put it) that resolves when the key is decrypted - what is `decrypt` ? and where does `config` even come from, you just use it in your code likes it's something that should always just be there - the fiddle is **identical in function** to your long winded, Promise constructor anti-pattern, code

Comment: `decrypt` calls the aws `kms.decrypt` function which returns `resolve(data.Plaintext.toString())` or `reject('some error message')`. Also `config` is just picking some stuff from config file.

Comment: @JaromandaX did add your suggestion, problem still persists though.

Comment: have you checked `headers.Authorization` before you `decrypt` it? Because you mutate this value. The second call to the method you're exporting may try to decrypt a non-encrypted `headers.Authorization`. And I don't know how decrypt deals with that.

Comment: @Thomas its a static value that I'm picking from a file. Have added that code as well into the question

Comment: @Gogo no it's not. At least not after the you have called your method once, because here `headers.Authorization = 'Basic ' + auth_token;` you're changing this value and you don't have the *"static value that I'm picking from a file"* anymore.

Comment: @Thomas thanks. This solved the issue. The function was running fine the first time, but not after that. I thought that since Lambda should be picking code from S3 for each execution(right?), the config file should remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

That's an AWS lambda bug. See the [issue at Bluebird's repo](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/1341) and [basic reproducing code](https://github.com/Type-Zero/promise-timeout-hang-js) for the issue.

This issue is not actually related to bluebird but to asynchronous code handling and scheduling on lambda's deployment. https://github.com/nervous-systems/cljs-lambda/issues/62. Here is another issue that reproduces the bug: https://github.com/nervous-systems/cljs-lambda/issues/62.

A user raises a common issue:

> Oh my god. Just in case anyone else lands here and makes my mistake: make sure you haven't accidentally deployed AWS.config.update(...) using a localhost endpoint instead of an actual AWS region-specific endpoint. That can present with similar symptoms as above (say, if the only async function you're using is accessing a DynamoDB document client) but for utterly different reasons.